# Get Normal data from smooth Normal

Tags: python, normals, mathematics

I don't know about "Shade Smooth", but I hope you can help me there.
If the mesh has "Shade Flat", then you can read every face with "polygons [i] .normal". Can I also read the "normals" from the "Shade Smooth" on the face from the point?
I have illustrated this better in the picture.
I can read 1, 3, 5 with "polygons [i] .normal".
How do I read 2, 4, 6? The "2" could be calculated with 1 and 3. But I have no idea how to calculate that in Blender. Can you read the normal from the "Shade Smooth", which is from the location within the triangle? The location in the triangle is not always central. This is just an example.

[image]